# RDS licensing servers HA

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, licensing, remote-desktop-services, rds

I'm trying to understand the correct way to configure two licensing servers for high availability, in per user mode.

I have 100 users, and 100 Cal's in total.
I have two licensing servers; lic1 and lic2, and my understanding is lic2 would only ever be used if lic1 was unavailable (eg: server was turned off)

Which of the two options below is correct to use, and would not breach the Remote Desktop Services license terms?

Option 1:

Install 50 Cal's on lic1 and 50 on lic2.

lic1 would over-issue licences because I'm using per user, and issue 100 licences even though only 50 Cal's are installed, but this would be ok because in total we own 100 cal licences

Option 2:

Install all 100 licences on lic1.

If lic1 ever went offline, lic2 would over issue all 100 licences but this is ok because it is temporary while we fix lic1 or move the cal licences over to lic2

Or is there an option that I have not thought of which should be used?

Also, where can I actually find a copy of the Remote Desktop Services license terms online?